# why should I use Ant Design over other front end library

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I am new to react and am wondering why everyone is using Ant Design for the front end design over other front-end libraries. Please explain to me why should I go with Ant Design.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `everybody` is not using Ant Design and you can use whichever you want or you can use none. Better chose a library which will cater to your needs than what the general opinion is.

Answer (score 3):

Ant design have rich components which are easily customizable, since its popular enough it  gets a good community support.

But Ant design bundle size is huge due to css .It uses momentjs for datatime related operations so momentjs copies all the localization files so try to configure the webpack as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enterprise-class UI designed for web applications.
2. A set of high-quality React components out of the box.
3. Written in TypeScript with predictable static types.
4. Whole package of design resources and development tools.
5. Internationalization support for dozens of languages.
6. Powerful theme customization in every detail.
7. Most of the International languages supported
8. Encourage natural user behavior and an object-oriented approach.
9. Ant Design aims to avoid complicated, messy designs and focuses on ensuring user certainty with consistent appearances.